# Getting sapply to have string elements

Tags: regex, r

I want R to print all elements from `a` in a particular format (into a given text file). So here's what I use:

```
 library(stringr)
 a <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
 b <- sapply(a, function(x) cat(str_c("* ", x, "\n")))
```

This basically works, but it adds some extra stuff, namely:

```
 > b
 * aa
 * bb
 * cc
 $aa
 NULL

 $bb
 NULL

 $cc
 NULL
```

Likewise, for instance `typeof(b[1])` is "list", but I'd expect it to be a string. I don't really get what's going on here. What makes R add this and what can I do to avoid it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact result you want? `cat` is not used to print to file (usually).  It's used to print to standard output. Also, please mention `library(stringr)` in your post so people know you're using it.

Comment: Hi Richard, the result I want is that it should simply print * aa\n* bb\n* cc, but no $aa NULL stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `paste0` and then `cat` with the `sep` argument. And then there's no need for `sapply`

```
> a <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
> b <- paste0("* ", a)
> cat(b, sep = "\n")
# * aa
# * bb
# * cc
```

The combination of `cat`, `str_c` and `sapply` is why you're getting a list as the result. `cat` prints first, which is why your list has `* aa\n* bb\n* cc` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that uses regular expressions.

```
new  <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]{2})", "*\\1", a)
> cat(new, sep = "\n")
```

The expression looks for a capturing group of two letters in a row, and substitutes for it an asterisk, and a space.

Then, call cat with the new line separator.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind for this was actually `sprintf`:

```
cat(sprintf("* %s", a), sep = "\n")
```

---

However, this question is not entirely clear. It seems that on one level you want to be able to store this result and use it in this way later. In this case, maybe you want to consider defining your own `print` class, which isn't too difficult to do.

For example, here's a very basic `print` function for objects of `class` "myClass":

```
print.myClass <- function(x, ...) {
  # works on a basic vector or a list
  invisible(sapply(x, function(y) cat("* ", y, "\n")))
}
```

Let's see what it does...

First, create a copy of "a" and assign its `class` to be "myClass". Then, when you print it at the console, notice what happens:

```
b <- a
class(b) <- c(class(b), "myClass")
b
# *  aa 
# *  bb 
# *  cc
```

It will work with a basic `list` too:

```
bL <- split(a, a)
class(bL) <- c(class(bL), "myClass")
bL
# *  aa 
# *  bb 
# *  cc
```

And, since `class` is just an `attribute`, you can always call `print.default` or wrap the output in `unclass`:

```
print.default(bL)
# $aa
# [1] "aa"
# 
# $bb
# [1] "bb"
# 
# $cc
# [1] "cc"
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "list"    "myClass"
```

And, as you expected:

```
typeof(bL[[1]])
# [1] "character"
```

For fun, also try...

```
## unclass(bL)
## unclass(b)
## print.myClass(a)
```